# Get value from form and pass it to function in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mapbox-gl

2 fields are for map coordinates( longitude/latitude )
how to bind input field, when any coordinated pass in, map coordinates will update automatically

**HTML**

```
<label>Longitude</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.lon">
<label>Longitude</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.lat">
```

**JS**

```
function Controller($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        zoom: 9,
        center: [0, 0],
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    });

    map.flyTo({ center: [vm.lon, vm.lat], zoom: 7 });

}
```

using mapbox for maps, and it should be without submit button.

Comment: try to declare `vm.lon` and `vm.lat` in your controller...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please refactor your code first.

```
<label>Longitude</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-keyup="vm.change()" ng-model="vm.data.lon">
<label>Longitude</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-keyup="vm.change()" ng-model="vm.data.lat">

function Controller() {
var vm = this;
vm.data={};
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    zoom: 9,
    center: [0, 0],
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
});
vm.change=function(){
   map.flyTo({ center: [vm.data.lon, vm.data.lat], zoom: 7 });
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

try this once declaring lon and lat in your controller...

```
function Controller($scope) {
$scope.vm = {
lon:'',
lat:''};

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    zoom: 9,
    center: [0, 0],
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
});

map.flyTo({ center: [$scope.vm.lon, $scope.vm.lat], zoom: 7 });
}
```